# Meteor event.target.files is undefined?

Tags: javascript, file, meteor

Following code for the template:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And then in my events for that template:

```
'submit form': function (event, template)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var file = event.target.files;
    var title = event.target.title.value;
    var image = Images.insert(file[0], function (err, fileObj)
    {

    });
    Bla.insert({name: title, userId: '123123', image: image._id});
}
```

Now I am getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

So `event.target.files` is undefined, but I don't get why.

When I just use the file input and then a change event handler on that + jQuery get to get the file, it works.

Comment: `console.log` your whole event and look through that, you'll find out where your files are stored in the event.

Comment: Oke I am stupid. I had to do event.target.[name-of-field].files... But shouldn't event.target.files work, too? Thank you. If you make an answer I will accept it

Comment: there's no reason of feeling stupid. I apologize to you if my earlier comment made you feel stupid. JQuery event and meteor events are not the same. they do handle things differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `console.log` your event and you'll get the location of your files where it's stored in the event. it'll be similar like this

```
event.target.[name-of-field].files
```

Comment: Okay one more thing, don't get me wrong, but this has nothing to do with jQuery / meteor event. The event is from javascript, jQuery doesn't have it's own "event" object. It was just because the .files only works on a file input, not on the whole event.